# JDBC ResultSet Scroll Sensitive Type and Result Set Scroll Insensitive Type

Tags: java, jdbc

can someone please tell me difference between JDBC ResultSet Scroll Sensitive Type and Result Set Scroll Insensitive Type?

Where we use these usually in projects?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The type of a ResultSet object determines the level of its functionality in two areas: the ways in which the cursor can be manipulated, and *how concurrent changes made to the underlying data source are reflected by the ResultSet object.*

**TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE**:

> The result can be scrolled; its cursor can move both forward and
>   backward relative to the current position, and it can move to an
>   absolute position. The result set is insensitive to changes made to
>   the underlying data source while it is open. It contains the rows that
>   satisfy the query at either the time the query is executed or as the
>   rows are retrieved.

**TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE**:

> The result can be scrolled; its cursor can move both forward and
>   backward relative to the current position, and it can move to an
>   absolute position. The result set reflects changes made to the
>   underlying data source while the result set remains open.

Refer [javase tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

ResultSet Scroll Sensitive Type (`TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE`) : specifies that a resultset is scrollable in either direction and is affected by changes committed by other transactions or statements within the same transaction.

Result Set Scroll Insensitive Type (`TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE`) : specifies that a resultset is scrollable in either direction but is insensitive to changes committed by other transactions or other statements in the same transaction.

Also check [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)

Answer (score 0):

scrollable resultset(TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE) and non-scrollable resultset(TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE) are two types of `Resultset` objects based on their sensivity. Resultset is an object used to access a database from a java EE application.

> The ResultSet object has a cursor, which initially does not point to any record. Call ResultSet's first() function to move the cursor to the first record held by the ResultSet object. ResultSet's get functions provide access to the contents of each column using the column name from the database table

Non-scrollable resultset can only move in forward direction from first to last element and also they cannot move directly to any row in the database.

Whereas a Scrollable resultset can traverse in both direction i.e. either forward or backward and also it can point to any row in the database at any point of time which makes it much more flexible.

**Reference:** [difference between scroll-able ResultSet ans non-scroll-able ResultSet object?](http://www.opengurukul.com/vlc/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=533)